# Draw a Line between two points and zoom on the new layer - PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

In my QGIS3 Plug-in I have this code to draw a line between two points. The code works, but after running it, QGIS zooms somewhere in the middle of Pacific Ocean, when I'd like to zoom on the new layer ("line"). The problem occurs at the last line of this code when I call `addMapLayers()`.

```
def drawLine(self, line_start, line_end):
  start_point = QgsPoint(line_start.asPoint())
  end_point = QgsPoint(line_end.asPoint())        
  v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "line", "memory")
  pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
  seg = QgsFeature()
  seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point]))
  pr.addFeatures( [ seg ] )
  v_layer.updateExtents()
  crs = v_layer.crs()
  crs.createFromId(4326)
  v_layer.setCrs(crs)
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
```

I tried to add `iface.zoomToActiveLayer()` but nothing changed. How can I zoom on this new layer avoiding the Pacific Ocean issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the CRS when you construct your `QgsVectorLayer` object e.g.

```
v_layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=epsg:4326', 'line', 'memory')
```

Unfortunately, you don't show us what objects you are passing to your `drawLine()` function as the `line_start` and `line_end` arguments, however running the code below which directly creates `QgsPoint()` objects for the `start_point` and `end_point` works fine in the Python console in QGIS 3.4.

```
start_point = QgsPoint(135.0, -15.0)
end_point = QgsPoint(137.5, -16.5)
v_layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=epsg:4326', 'line', 'memory')
pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point]))
pr.addFeatures([ seg ])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried to specify CRS and nothing changed. Then I tried your code with your points in my plugin and the same thing happens: the line is created but QGIS zooms in the middle of the Ocean. I confirm that it works in the Python console, so there's a problem in my plugin. I can't understand the reason of this beavior because I simply call the function `drawLine()`, nothing more.